# Usually getting spinning wheel when trying to log into Twitter with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, twitter, puppeteer

Most of the time when I try to log into Twitter, it allows me to enter my username or email but then shows a permanent spinning wheel instead of showing me the screen where it asks for my password. I've defeated complex problems with other social media such as Facebook, but this is stumping me. Previous solutions on Stack Overflow for this problem are outdated and aren't even set up for the two page login that Twitter now uses.

I've tried a variety of approaches including running this program on a Linux machine in the cloud and on my home Windows machine. I've had more luck on my Windows machine, likely because there is some flaw in my stealth routines which are the vast majority of the code that I am posting here.

The spinning wheel shows in twitter.output.png when this program fails. If you see a question asking for your password in that screenshot, then this program will work with final output at twitter.good.output.png.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');

const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(pluginStealth())
const fs = require('fs');

async function run()
{

browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: true,
args: [
  '--no-sandbox',
  '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
  '--window-size=1920,2700', // Maybe 5400, 10800 is too big and sometimes the page doesn't fully load?
  '--lang=en-US,en;q=0.9' // Fool https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20480915
],
userDataDir: "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/selenium3"
});

page = await browser.newPage();

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
password = await fs.readFileSync('twitter.password.attached.to.email','utf8').trim();
email = await fs.readFileSync('twitter.email','utf8').trim();
username = await fs.readFileSync('twitter.username','utf8').trim();
await page.setUserAgent(user_agent);

const stealthFile = `// Pass the Webdriver Test from http://willless.com/puppeteer-%E6%97%A0%E5%A4%B4%E6%A8%A1%E5%BC%8F%E5%8F%8D%E5%8F%8D%E7%88%AC%E8%AE%BE%E7%BD%AE%E6%B1%87%E6%80%BB.html
const newProto = navigator.__proto__;
delete newProto.webdriver;
navigator.__proto__ = newProto;

// Add the window.chrome field and fill it with some values
window.chrome = {};
window.chrome.app = {
   InstallState: 'hehe',
   RunningState: 'haha',
   getDetails: 'xixi',
   getIsInstalled: 'ohno',
};
window.chrome.csi = function () {};
window.chrome.loadTimes = function () {};
window.chrome.runtime = function () {};

// Set up Permissions
const originalQuery = window.navigator.permissions.query; //notification??
window.navigator.permissions.query = (parameters) =>
   parameters.name === 'notifications'
    ? Promise.resolve({ state: Notification.permission })
    : originalQuery(parameters);

// WebGL Setup
const getParameter = WebGLRenderingContext.getParameter;
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter = function (parameter) {
   // UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL
   if (parameter === 37445) {
      return 'Intel Inc.';
   }
   // UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL
   if (parameter === 37446) {
      return 'Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100';
   }
   return getParameter(parameter);
};

// Pass navigator.connection.rtt Test
Object.defineProperty(navigator.connection, 'rtt', {
   get: () => 50
});

// Bypass hairline feature
// store the existing descriptor
const elementDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
  HTMLElement.prototype,
  "offsetHeight"
);

// redefine the property with a patched descriptor
Object.defineProperty(HTMLDivElement.prototype, "offsetHeight", {
  ...elementDescriptor,
  get: function() {
    if (this.id === "modernizr") {
      return 1;
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    return elementDescriptor.get.apply(this);
  },
});`;

await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(stealthFile);

console.log('Going to Twitter');
await page.goto('https://twitter.com');
await page.waitForTimeout(6000+Math.random() * 6000);
console.log('Clicking on login');
[buttonElement] = await page.$x('//a[@href="/login"]');
buttonElement.click();
await page.waitForTimeout(6000+Math.random() * 6000);
[inputElement] = await page.$x('//input[@autocomplete="username"]');
inputElement.click();
await page.waitForTimeout(3000+Math.random() * 3000);
await page.keyboard.type(email);
console.log('Sending email');
await page.waitForTimeout(6000+Math.random() * 6000);
[buttonElement] = await page.$x("//div[@role='button']/descendant::span[text()='Next']");
buttonElement.click();
console.log('Clicking on next button');
await page.waitForTimeout(6000+Math.random() * 6000);

// Sometimes Twitter wants an email and username
html = await page.content();
if (html.match(/please enter your phone number or username/i))
{
 await page.keyboard.type(username+"\n");
 await page.waitForTimeout(6000+Math.random() * 6000);
}

console.log('Saving screenshot for Stack Overflow');
await page.screenshot({path: 'twitter.output.png'});
await page.waitForTimeout(6000+Math.random() * 6000);

// If things are O.K., keep going...
total = 30 + Math.random() * 10;
i = 0;
while (i++ < total)
{
 await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
}

await page.keyboard.type(password+"\n");
await page.waitForTimeout(3000+Math.random() * 3000);
await page.screenshot({path: 'twitter.good.output.png'});
await page.waitForTimeout(6000+Math.random() * 6000);

browser.close(); process.exit();
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got some time to work on the problem and solved it!

The solution was to type `npm i puppeteer@latest` at the command prompt.

While working on the problem before, I didn't realize that the module puppeteer-extra which this code loads was itself loading the module puppeteer and my puppeteer module was out-of-date.

For a while, there was an "answer" that someone had posted here that thought my problem was the various delays built into the program. Those delays just make the program run slowly to look more human, they don't cause it to malfunction.

Now, I'll be able to do things like post to my own feed. The new Twitter APIs that are being released are horrific where even the $100/month option doesn't handle my fairly light needs. I read many complaints where someone tested the $100/month API for an hour and then found they had already hit their limits for a full month and were very surprised.